# Temperature dependence of the energy bandgap and Simulink way

Tags: energy, simulink

I know the equation about the temperature change of band energy

[image: Varshni Empirical Expression]

but Simulink must find another way to define it like below.

[image: Simulink way]

dEg=-2.677 10^-4

I can't find a single reference about that equation. I hope someone in here know it.

Comment: What simulink model? can you name/link a block/page where this equation is mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation you give is simply the empirical [Varshni](https://doi.org/10.1016/0031-8914(67)90062-6) equation linearized about a given reference temperature.

To convert from one to the other, evaluate the Varshni equation at the reference temperature to find Egref and differentiate with respect to temperature, and evaluate the derivative at the reference temperature to find the slope of the linearized curve (use the quotient rule).

If I substitute the following values for silicon (from [this](http://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/eband5.htm) source) into the equation:

Eg(0) = 1.166

\$\alpha\$ = 4.73E-4

\$\beta\$ = 636

It looks like the reference temperature should be approximately 55°C for your equation to agree with the above numbers (assuming silicon).

From the above-linked site:

[image]

On the other hand, if you retrieve [Y.P. Varshni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y._P._Varshni)'s original paper (as above, but behind a paywall) the numbers given are quite different (1.1557/7.021E-4/1108) and agree with the Simulink slope coefficient at the more expected 300K.